# Why is this a forward declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, forward-declaration

I will have the following code snippet in utilA.cpp:

```
// utilB.h
namespace xm
{
     void zoo(struct tm timeval);  //<-----line 0
}


// utilA.cpp
#include <utilB.h>                 //<----line 1
#include <time.h>                  //<----line 2
namespace xm
{
     void foo()
     {
         struct tm time1 = {0};    //<----line 3
     }
}
```

GCC complains when compiling utilA.cpp,

```
error: variable 'xm::tm time1' has initializer but incomplete type
```

It seems this is because the `utilA.h` is using `struct tm` in line 0, but without include the `time.h`, and the compiler treat the `struct tm` in line 0 as a forward declare, so the `struct tm` at line 2 is resolved as `xm::tm` inside the header at line 0.

So does the C++ standard define this `struct tm` as an type of function parameter as forward declaration? Please help to explain this and quotes from the standard will helpful.

Comment: Write `#include <time.h>` in your header since your header depends on it.

Comment: Yes, we should add #include <time.h> in utilB.h, but because this is code snippet from an huge project, it confused us a lot before we find the root cause.

Comment: This is very bad style of programming. Ignore it. PS: Have you tried to move `#include`-s to the top?

Comment: @molbdnilo They don't need the definition of `tm` for the declaration of `zoo`. Unless you meant to say that you cannot forward-declare standard library types, in which case you'd be right

Comment: @krzaq No, but every use of `zoo` is going to need the definition. It's good form to have self-contained headers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In line 0, you declared a class named `tm` inside the `xm` namespace. Yes, C++ allows declaring types in function/template parameters.

> N4140 § 3.4.4 [basic.lookup.elab]/2
>
> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* and
>   this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or if the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier*;
>
> the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in 3.3.2.

Because you declared a class named `tm` inside the `xm` namespace, it's the first name that name lookup finds for `tm` in line 3. `::tm` (and `::std::tm`) are not considered. And since there's no definition of class `::xm::tm`, the compiler complains about it being an incomplete type.

If you weren't writing C code in C++, you'd write something like<sup>1</sup>

```
struct tm;

namespace xz{
    void zoo(tm timeval);
}
```

or

```
#include <ctime>

namespace xz{
    void zoo(tm timeval);
}
```

and you wouldn't have that problem.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>remember that you cannot forward-declare names in namespace std</sub>

Answer (score 7):

> So does C++ standard define this `struct tm` as an type of function parameter as forward declaration. Please help to explain this and quota from the standard will helpful.

Yes, `struct tm timeval` will introduce a new class name `xm::tm` here.

---

(explanations and quotes)

`struct tm` is a [elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier), which could be used to introduce a new class name.

[$3.1/4 Declarations and definitions [basic.def]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#4)

> [ Note: A class name can also be implicitly declared by an elaborated-type-specifier ([dcl.type.elab]).  — end note ]

[$9.1/2 Class names [class.name]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2):

> A declaration consisting solely of class-key identifier; is either a
>   redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward
>   declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class
>   name into the current scope.

[$3.4.4/2 Elaborated type specifiers [basic.lookup.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2):

> or if the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the
>   form:
>
> ```
> class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
> ```
>
> the elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in [basic.scope.pdecl].

[$3.3.2/7 Point of declaration [basic.scope.pdecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#7):

> if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or
>   parameter-declaration-clause of a function defined in namespace scope,
>   the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration;

For `struct tm timeval` used as function parameter declaration, because `<time.h>` is not included and there's still no class named `tm`, class `tm` will be declared in current scope (i.e. namespace `xm`), then `xm::tm` will be forward declared.